# How to find control inside table which is inside gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to get the ID of the **ASP control inside a table and the table is inside a gridview**... 
Here's the code to give you a better idea:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvTest" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="lblTestLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

I have no problem getting the **control inside a gridview** and here's the code:

```
function TestFunction(sender, e)   {
    var gridview = document.getElementById('gvTest.ClientID');
    var i = gridview.rows.length - 1;
    var node1 = gridview.rows[i].cells[1].children[0];
}
```

But I need to put table inside gridview for formatting issues and when I did it, the controls are not accessible ....
So my question is how can I get the ID of the ASP label (in this case, lblTestLabel") in javascript?

Comment: What do you mean by "the controls are not accessible when the table comes in"?

Comment: Are you using masterpages? Then the control name gets replaced at runtime. You can see the "real" name by using firebug then.
The best way to retrieve a control is using jQuery where you can access it using place holders like var value =  $('[id$=lblTestLabel]').val();

Comment: its definetly not a trick question ,you just didnt google it correctly

Comment: Problem solved now. Thanks to you @UNeverNo. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using masterpages the control name gets replaced at runtime. You can see the "real" name debugging it pressing F12 inside the browser (download firebug for firefox).

The best way to retrieve a control is using jQuery where you can access it using place holders like

```
var value = $('[id$=lblTestLabel]').val();
```